# Javascript to remove second word from among 2 words phrase without altering first word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my actual code

```
<div class="bigright ">
   <ul>
       <li id="cp_ad_type" class=""><span>Ad Type:</span> Offer Ads</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Actual Output:**

- **Ad Type:** Offer Ads

Expected Code

```
<div class="bigright ">
   <ul>
       <li id="cp_ad_type" class=""><span>Ad Type:</span> Offer</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Expected Output**

- **Ad Type:** Offer

I want to remove **Ads** word from **Offer Ads** phrase without altering **Offer** word as shown in Expected Output & code. Bcoz ***Ad Type*** may change between **Offer Ads** or **Wanted Ads** depending upon user choice. So common word is **Ads** in both **Offer** & **Wanted**. I just want to remove to that **Ads** Word.

Help needed!!

Comment: $('#cp_ad_type').html($('#cp_ad_type').html().replace('Ads', ''));

Comment: Also, your HTML hardly qualifies as "actual code."    
    
You'll need to post what Javascript you have running on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this;

```
var target = $('#cp_ad_type');
target.html(target.html().replace(/(Offer|Wanted) Ads/, "$1"));
```

Or, sometimes simpler in plain javascript:

```
var target = document.getElementById('#cp_ad_type');
target.innerHTML = target.innerHTML.replace(/(Offer|Wanted) Ads/, "$1");
```

Comment: @DavidThomas - it wasn't entirely clear what kind of code the OP wanted.  My code shows them how to do it, they can adapt it either way.  If there are only two possibilities, Offer Ads and Wanted Ads, then I've modified my replace to include both.  Or, this could be made into a function that passes in the targets.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ktz2d/)

```
$('div.bigright li:contains("Ads")').text(function (_, old_txt) {
    return old_txt.replace('Ads', '')
});
```

References

[:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text)

[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

Complicated description of a simple problem. Just remove the word `Ads` from it

```
yourString.replace(" Ads","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = $('#cp_ad_type').html();
var new_html = html.substring(0,html.length - 'Ads'.length);
$('#cp_ad_type').html(new_html);
```

**[JSBIN of the working code](http://jsbin.com/iloGIpU/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

if you are using PHP or Javascript or the like use Regular Expresions to target the string

Example in Javascript with jQuery for simplicity:
This will replace the `<li>` with the id of "cp_ad_type" text to the text of that `<li>` without what matches in the regular expression.

```
var exStr = /[^Ads]/g;
$('#cp_ad_type').text(exStr.exec($("#cp_ad_type").text()));
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do here.  `.exec()` returns an array which you are then putting back into the text?